# How do I solve "Expected named arguments" for freeStyleJob?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I have several different projects that will be compiled in Jenkins and shall be uploaded to my Nexus3 repository. For that I am using the NexusArtifcalUploader. For some reason I get the following error message although the code is essentially copied from the plugin page of the Jenkins wiki.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [clientmoduleNexusArtifactUploaderJob, org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@63d801fc]
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:511)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeDescribable(DSL.java:291)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:153)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor463.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  ...
```

My Jenkinsfile calls the `uploadToNexus` method I created which creates freeStyleJobs:

```
def uploadToNexus(module) {
  def groupId = "com.example"
  def moduleVersions = [
          "client-module": "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
          "server-module": "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
  ]

  def moduleVersion = moduleVersions.get(module)
  def jobName = "${fixModuleName(module)}NexusArtifactUploaderJob"

  echo "will run freeStyleJob ${jobName} now..."
  freeStyleJob(jobName) {
    steps {
      nexusArtifactUploader {
        nexusVersion('nexus3')
        protocol('http')
        nexusUrl('nexus:8081')
        groupId(groupId)
        version(moduleVersion)
        repository('maven2_central')
        credentialsId('nexus_admin')
        artifact {
          artifactId('${module}')
          type('war')
          classifier('debug')
          file('${module}.war')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To my knowledge freeStyleJob expects a string which I pass, don't I? What am I missing and doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I mixed up Job DSL and Pipeline DSL. I wasn't aware there's a difference.

Here's a way to use Job DSL inside Pipeline DSL: 
https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/User-Power-Moves#use-job-dsl-in-pipeline-scripts